# Should I add a method to a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know *how* to add a method to an object in JavaScript, but my question is whether and when it is appropriate to do this for a DOM object.

Suppose, for example, I have a function

```
function add_header(table, title) {
    var header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
}
```

which adds a header to a given table object. It seems natural to replace this global function with a method added either to the main table in my web page or to the table prototype. But it seems possible that this might confuse a future browser or library.

Are there compelling arguments one way (global function with the object passed as an argument) or the other (method added to DOM object)? What is the standard practice?

Comment: *"Are there compelling arguments one way (global function with the object passed as an argument) or the other (method added to DOM object)?"* Yes. Both. :-)

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: It is generally accepted that augmenting native objects (either JavaScript or browser) is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @CBroe . I don't suppose you would like to expand that into an answer?

Comment: Well, link-only answers are not really desired here ... would prefer if you wrote a self-answer, and explained a little bit what new insights you gained from that article.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a very complex language. Don't make it more complex by scattering codes!

You should have a Helper script. Document that file accordingly.